# init / sync mnesia on distributed rebar3 app

Tags: erlang, distributed, mnesia

I have a rebar3 app which starts an Mnesia DB.
I want to backup this DB on another node, so I've copied the code to another computer and tried to sync the nodes according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522902/how-to-run-an-application-distributed-using-rebar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787755/how-to-add-a-node-to-an-mnesia-cluster).
Unfortunately I'm getting:
`Mnesia('node1@pc1'): ** ERROR ** mnesia_event got {inconsistent_database, running_partitioned_network, 'node2@pc2'}`

I'm setting the cookie in-code, and the DBs are identical, so this doesn't make sense to me. The cookie in the error dumps is a bit different tho.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, apparently I didn't follow the right startup protocol:
According to the [Mnesia doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/mnesia_chap3) all nodes start an empty schema, then the master nodes creates the schema with the relevant nodes, and then there's a sync/connect message between the nodes.
This means that each node at startup has to check whether it is the master node and create the schema, or just init mnesia.